# How Do I organise My Photos on Various Devices

Tags: storage, sync

My photo files are a mess. They are randomly distributed between my desktop computer, iPad and mobile phone, sometimes duplicated and sometimes not. I need to get organised.

I have a Mac desktop, an iPad and an Android phone. How should I organise my photos so that they are synchronised across the three devices?

Basically I would like a master set of photos on the desktop, and then copies or access from my phone and iPad. My phone has plenty of memory (32Gb internal + 32Gb SD card) so I would prefer to hold copies on the phone rather than have to access them from the cloud every time, and I often don't have a good 4G signal. The iPad is only used at home with a good wifi and fibre connection, so that could access photos from elsewhere when needed.

I appreciate that it would have been easier to arrange this if I was starting from zero, but I'm not. I have 20-odd years worth of digital photos in a jumble of folders and locations. I need a solution that can be applied to the present mess without too much pain. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, this is somewhat subjective. But I’d argue it’s good subjective and should be a fit for this site. Some general organizational guidelines would apply across devices and shooters - making it a perfectly valid question. The solution to this is very relevant to pro shooters and biz questions are also very on topic.

Comment: I politely disagree. This question can simply not be answered conclusively, although I too would be interested in the various options for photo organization.